# Dynamic object to hold temporary data

Tags: c#

I am creating `Generic parser` which will parse any type of file and convert file data into an object.
Example: CSV file contains Product data will convert to Product object.

My approach is:
I have a class `MainParser` that will take the file name and then depending on the type of file I pass it to respective parser like CSV, excel, word parsers.

What I am looking here is I want to make an intermediate object which will first contain the data then that data can be parsed to respective object. The intermediate object is output of individual parser then I convert that intermediate object to final object in main parser then return it to caller application.

The benefit of using intermediate object is all validations while converting the file data to final object will be at one place.

What kind of object can I use to hold temporary data...what are best practices here... ?

Comment: I believe you want to take a look at type providers.

Comment: You want a generic type to hold the structure of any type of file... ? Sounds like you're asking for the impossible. Your only option I can think of is a `byte` array...

Comment: @Leri: Can you me more details or some link ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: What I am thinking, I can parse the file and keep data into the temporary intermediate object and then again I will iterate the temporary intermediate object and convert into actual or final type object.

Comment: @user2463514 Sure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156509.aspx

Comment: @Leri: I guess this will not work for me...as I am using Visual Studio 2010 and C# for development.

Comment: @user2463514 1. You need to upgrade. 2. There already should be ready type providers for common formats (_hint:_ google).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try something like

```
class MainParser {
  public MyObject Parse(Filename file){
    //Build the relevant parser implementation according to the type of the file 
    IParser myParser = ParserFactory.BuildParser(file) 

    //Build the intermediate object
    DTOObject intermediateObject = myParser.Parse(file);

    //Finish the build
    return BuildMyObject(intermediateObject);
  }

  private MyObject BuildMyObject(DTOObject dtoObject){
     //Do validation and so on
  }
}
```

Here the intermediate object is just a kind of [Data Transfer Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transfer_Object), and you just store it temporarily in a local variable since you won't need it after the final object has been built.

Comment: Thanks for defining skeleton. I am doing almost the same thing but what type could be intermediate object "DTOObject". Number of columns are not fixed ?

Comment: Later on the problem is iteration also..when I convert intermediate object to actual object.

Comment: It would be easier to provide a relevant answer if we have an idea of what your object would look like. What do columns represent (eg: 1st=name, 2nd=age, ...)? Or are they just arbitrary data? Also, what kind of iteration are we talking about? Maybe your could edit your question to add this information.

Comment: Its a generic parser the file contains any type of data (like product,category,orders etc)

Comment: By iteration I mean...first copying/parsing excel data to intermediate object then copying intermediate object data to final object.

Comment: If the columns have titles, you could use a `Map<string, string>`. Otherwise, what about a `List<string>`?

Comment: So do u think any issue in the complete approach..in terms of performance or any other issues ?